# MySQL Syntax Error while updating multiple columns

Tags: java, mysql, syntax-error

I am trying to update user profile by taking input through a jsp form and storing it into a table in MYSQL Workbench using servlet. I am getting a Syntax Error while updating the table.

```
ps = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("UPDATE user SET user_id =?, FName=? , LName=?,  City=? , Email=? , Country=? , DOB=?, JobPosition=?, Profile_Picture=? WHERE user_id=123");
        ps.setInt(1, UserId);
        ps.setString(2, Fname);
        ps.setString(3, Lname);
        ps.setString(4, City);
        ps.setString(5, EmailId);
        ps.setString(6, Country);
        ps.setDate(7, java.sql.Date.valueOf(DOB));
        ps.setString(8, JobPosition);
        if (inputStream != null) {
            ps.setBlob(9, inputStream);
        }
```

[EDIT]

Error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''techquo'.'user' set user_id =123, FName='Default' , LName='Default',  City='' ,' at line 1
```

This is my SQL query. I am new to this and cannot figure out what's wrong with the syntax. The table name and the name of attributes are correct. I have rechecked. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the error?

Comment: You did notice the missing `WHERE` clause in your `UPDATE` statement, right? You do know that will cause MySQL to update every row in your table, right?

Comment: @O.Jones yes, i am aware of that, actually this is just one module of a project and the table isnt populated yet, so I was just trying to test this module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user` is a reserved keyword. see the docs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)

try wrapping it in backticks:

```
ps = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("Update `user` set user_id =?, FName=? , LName=?,  City=? , Email=? , Country=? , DOB=?, JobPosition=?, Profile_Picture=?");
```

also, there is no `where` clause, so the update will be applied to all the rows - Probably not what you want.

Comment: sir i tried that. Still showing the same error. But thanks for the tip, i wasn't aware that user is a reserved keyword.